# How to make sure that the object gets updated from module to the downstream?

Tags: python

I'm not sure if my title is misleading but I'm a python noob. I'm doing an interface for Vault. What it's doing is just renewing the keys every 30s so the client doesn't have to do it. Otherwise the secret will expire or change and the client using the key will get an error. I'm using python `threading` to renew the keys. Here's my code.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import hvac
import time
import threading
import os


VAULT_URL = os.environ['VAULT_ADDR']
VAULT_TOKEN = os.environ['VAULT_TOKEN']


class Client:
    def __init__(self, *keys):
        self.keys = keys
        self.data_dict = {}
        self.client = hvac.Client(
            url=VAULT_URL,
            token=VAULT_TOKEN)

        self.__renew()

    def read(self):
        for key in self.keys:
            self.data_dict[key] = self.client.read(key)
        return self.data_dict

    def __renew(self):
        self.client.renew_token()
        threading.Timer(30, self.__renew).start()
        self.read()
```

And this is how it's being used.

```
from cnvault.cnvault import Client

data_dict = Client('secret/key').read()

// This is for web.py just to test
class ping:
      def GET(self):
          print(data_dict)
          return 'pong'
```

Now if I change the data in Vault using Vault CLI and I call `/ping`, I'm still seeing old data.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "call `/ping`"?

Comment: It's just I have web.py exposes `/ping` so I can do `http://localhost:8080/ping` to get the data.

Comment: I can change the code if it's confusing.